# PHP object array navigation

Tags: php, xml, rss, blogger

I'm pulling data from a Blogger RSS feed. I have most of it narrowed down how I would like it to be, except for one thing. In the following object, how would I get the string in the term section? I've tried about every syntax I can think of, but I honestly have run out of ideas.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["scheme"]=>
    string(31) "http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#"
    ["term"]=>
    string(7) "happens"
  }
}
```

I've tried to `var_dump` `$item->attributes`and `$item->@attributes` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
$atts = $xml->attributes();
echo $atts['term'];
```

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
$xml->attributes()->{'term'};
```

Comment: I used the alternative. I ended up doing

`echo "Term:".$item->attributes()->term."<br/>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($object->{'@attributes'}['term']);
```

or

```
$tmp = '@attributes';
var_dump($object->{$tmp}['term']);
```